# how to upload a file to gmail using delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am creating an application which uploads file to gmail account avilable space

can any one please tell me the best way to do it ?

i read somewhere about using IMAP protocol is the best way to upload files or is there any other good way around ?

regards

Comment: Do you want to send an E-Mail to your own G-Mail Account with a file (attachment)?

Comment: i want to create a tool like this http://www.viksoe.dk/code/gmail.htm

Comment: Which is fully based around sending an e-mail to your G-Mail account with a file attachment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GMail is not suitable for keeping generic files. Google offers Documents and Data API mechanisms for storing files. You might want to look at them. BTW we have products, which combined let you create a virtual drive with Google backend storage in a couple of hours. [Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/) offers a virtual drive, and [CloudBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-cloud.php) lets you store data on Amazon S3, MS Azure and on GMail storages.

Comment: A much better approach than using GMail. Plus Google Docs offers more than enough space for most users as well and if you already have a GMail account, all you need to do is activate it (sign up with the same e-mail address).